# How to modify a function of a library in a module

Tags: r, namespaces, package

I have the following problem - in a script starting like that:

```
modules::import("modules")
modules::import("futile.logger")
modules::import("data.table")
modules::import("REDCapR")
```

used as a module using `modules::use` in an other script, I would like to use a modified version of the function `redcap_write` of the package `REDCapR`.

I don't know how to proceed. To my point of view there are two possibilities:

- Use a modified version of `redcap_write` stored locally. That would be great, because it would be an easy mofication to share. But I don't know how to force R to replace the `redcap_write` function of the package by my local modified version. `modules::use` would only import the modified function but would not replace the package version of `redcap_write`
- Install a forked version of `REDCapR` package, that I created here https://github.com/dmongin/REDCapR/tree/overwrite. But I don't know how to do in a simple manner (uninstalling `REDCapR` to install my forked version would be a bit tidious: we share the code between various developper/users, each should uninstall and reinstall the package)

Answer (score 5):

You would have to modify the things under the package Namespace. Here is one example replacing `redcap_write()` with the `mean()` function.

```
ns <- asNamespace("REDCapR")
fn <- "redcap_write"

unlockBinding(fn, ns)
ns[[fn]] <- mean
lockBinding(fn, ns)
```

Check if it worked:

```
library(REDCapR)

> redcap_write
function (x, ...)
UseMethod("mean")
<bytecode: 0x7f8120229100>
<environment: namespace:base>

> REDCapR::redcap_write
function (x, ...)
UseMethod("mean")
<bytecode: 0x7f8120229100>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

EDIT:

In order to `redcap_write` to call the proper functions inside its body, you have to set it in the `REDCapR` environment. This should work (assuming `newversion` is your corrected `redcap_write` function):

```
ns <- asNamespace("REDCapR")
fn <- "redcap_write"
unlockBinding(fn, ns)
environment(newversion) <- ns
ns[[fn]] <- newversion
lockBinding(fn, ns)
```

Comment: I will check that as soon as I can. It looks promising, I just want to verify how it is handled with the `modules` structure

Comment: It is not working as I expect it. All the non exported functions called inside my modified `redcap_write()` do not work, so the call to to the modified function gives an error. I tried to include them as a module, but I still get errors

Comment: Maybe try adding those non-exported functions under the same namespace: `ns[["fun1"]] <- function1; ns[["fun2"]] <- function2;`.

Comment: @denis Made an edit on the answer which hopefully addresses your last issue. Didn't post a new answer, since Karolis here was very close.

Comment: It does not work, because of the `modules` structure I guess.  My function `redcap_write` is indicated in `{modules:REDCapR}`, but I cannot do `asNamespace("modules:REDCapR")`. If I do what you propose in the edit, it does not modify the function loaded with `modules::import("REDCapR")`

Comment: But you don't need to do `asNamespace(modules:REDCapR)`. Just `asNamespace("REDCapR")`. Simply execute the code in the answer and then call `modules:import("REDCapR")`.

Comment: @denis Tested with `modules` today, and it seemed to be working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can reinstall your version instead using `remotes`. It will replace in the package previously installed:

```
install.packages("remotes") # Run this line if the 'remotes' package isn't installed already.
remotes::install_github("dmongin/REDCapR",branch="overwrite")
```

(taken from the original RedcapR Readme, updated for your fork).

Comment: doing `remotes::install_github(repo="dmongin/REDCapR/tree/overwrite")` (the branch with my modifs) I have `Downloading GitHub repo dmongin/REDCapR@HEAD
Error: Failed to install 'REDCapR' from GitHub:`

Comment: from [here](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1939) I tried  `Sys.setenv("TAR" = "internal")` but still the same error

Comment: @denis I edited the answer to select the `overwrite` branch.

Comment: Thanks! It does not install the modified version, I do not know why. It starts with ` remotes::install_github("dmongin/REDCapR",branch = "overwrite")
Downloading GitHub repo dmongin/REDCapR@HEAD`, install the package, but then the `redcap_write` function is the one from master. I manage to have the modified version by downloading my `overwrite` branch and building it locally.